# Overwrite the NotBlank Constraint Message on symfony2.1 globally?

Tags: php, symfony, constraints, message

How can I overwrite the `NotBlank` constraint message `This value should not be blank` globally throughout the Symfony 2.1 application?

I've tried with `validators.en.yml` files, but this works only if I set for every NotBlank constraint in my `validation.yml` files to a constant like `not.blank.field` - but is too much to modify.

Comment: Not tested but how about creating a file `<kernel root directory>/Resources/translations/validators.en.xlf` copied from https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Resources/translations/validators.en.xlf and just change the messages you want?

Comment: it doesn't work on validators.en.yml (or any other format) it works on messages.en.yml.. any ideea?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it works on messages.en.yml'?

Comment: @cheesemacfly - I mead that if I enter a translation rule for the message in the `messages.en.yml` it works (it changes my error message). but in the `validators.en.yml` has no effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace `This value should not be blank` message showing up when the `NotBlank` constraint is triggered at your application level, simply create the right translation file in the right place.

To make it simple, your locale seems to be English (en), so create the file `app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml` and write the following line in it:

```
# app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml
This value should not be blank.: Y U NO SET THE VALUE?!
```

The first part has to match exactly the message you want to translate (in your case `This value should not be blank.`).

If you have a custom files/folders hierarchy, simply create the file under `<kernel root directory>/Resources/translations`.

If you want to have the same behavior for another language (french for example), simply create the corresponding file in the same folder:

```
# app/Resources/translations/validators.fr.yml
This value should not be blank.: La valeur doit etre specifiee.
```

**Do not forget to clear your cache** after adding the new file!

Why does it work? Because Symfony2 priorities the translation files by locations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-locations-and-naming-conventions